# Software for testing XSS and other web sites vulnerabilities

Tags: xss, websites

One of my site would be submitted for vulnerability test, not sure if the company does this test manually.

I was wondering if i can find any software where I specify all variables names used in my website and automatically try to input code, script and other stuff in my form and pages to see if any vulnerability is open.

I don't trust online services, so I would really prefer something on my local machine, this would also let me do the test on local environment first.

Comment: This question will probably be closed shortly as it "seeks recommendations". XSSMe plugin for Firefox is worth taking a look, as is BURP suite if you want something a bit more 'pro' There is good documentation for both of these tools.

Comment: Other free options for this would be Arachni (http://www.arachni-scanner.com/) or OWASP ZAP (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some **Open Source** Web Application Vulnerability Scanners that support XSS scanning:

- **X5S**

> x5s is a [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) addon which aims to assist penetration testers in
>   finding cross-site scripting vulnerabilities. This is not a point and
>   shoot tool, it requires some understanding of how encoding issues lead
>   to XSS, and it requires manual driving.

Documentation: https://xss.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorial&referringTitle=Home
Download X5S: https://xss.codeplex.com/releases/view/43170

- **Grabber** :

> Grabber is a web application scanner. Basically it detects some kind
>   of vulnerabilities    in your website. Grabber is simple, not fast but
>   portable and really adaptable. This software is designed to scan small
>   websites such as personals, forums etc. absolutely not big
>   application: it would take too long time and flood your network.

Download it here: http://rgaucher.info/beta/grabber/
Source code on Github: https://github.com/neuroo/grabber

- **Vega:**

> Vega is a free and open source web security scanner and web security
>   testing platform to test the security of web applications. Vega can
>   help you find and validate SQL Injection, Cross-Site Scripting (XSS),
>   inadvertently disclosed sensitive information, and other
>   vulnerabilities. It is written in Java, GUI based, and runs on Linux,
>   OS X, and Windows.

Documentation: https://subgraph.com/vega/documentation/index.en.html
Download Vega: https://subgraph.com/vega/

- **ZAP:**

> Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP) is one of the world’s most popular free
>   security tools and is actively maintained by hundreds of international
>   volunteers*. It can help you automatically find security
>   vulnerabilities in your web applications while you are developing and
>   testing your applications. Its also a great tool for experienced
>   pentesters to use for manual security testing.

Documentation: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project
Download ZAP: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy

- **Wapiti**

> Wapiti allows you to audit the security of your web applications.
>
> It performs "black-box" scans, i.e. it does not study the source code
>   of the application but will scans the webpages of the deployed webapp,
>   looking for scripts and forms where it can inject data.
>
> Once it gets this list, Wapiti acts like a fuzzer, injecting payloads
>   to see if a script is vulnerable.

Documentation: http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/
Download Wapiti: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wapiti/files/

**- W3af:**

> w3af is a Web Application Attack and Audit Framework. The project’s
>   goal is to create a framework to help you secure your web applications
>   by finding and exploiting all web application vulnerabilities.

Documentation: http://w3af.org/
Download W3af: https://github.com/andresriancho/w3af/

**- WebScarab:**

> WebScarab is a framework for analysing applications that communicate
>   using the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. It is written in Java, and is thus
>   portable to many platforms. WebScarab has several modes of operation,
>   implemented by a number of plugins. In its most common usage,
>   WebScarab operates as an intercepting proxy, allowing the operator to
>   review and modify requests created by the browser before they are sent
>   to the server, and to review and modify responses returned from the
>   server before they are received by the browser. WebScarab is able to
>   intercept both HTTP and HTTPS communication. The operator can also
>   review the conversations (requests and responses) that have passed
>   through WebScarab.

Documentation: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project 
Download WebScarab: https://github.com/OWASP/OWASP-WebScarab
XSS plugin: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Webscarab_XSS-CRLF_plugin

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Check XSSer:

https://xsser.03c8.net/

It is an automatic -framework- to detect, exploit and report XSS vulnerabilities in web-based applications